# AWS RDS Postgres Logical replication

Tags: postgresql, replication, amazon-rds, aws

I am using AWS RDS Postgres's and RDS's [logical replication support](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-rds-for-postgresql-new-minor-versions-logical-replication-dms-and-more/)

(*Edit: Note, this is not the same as the logical replication featurein PostgreSQL 10. It's AWS RDS functionality based on the same underlying logical decoding feature.*)

I'm replicating Postgres -> Postgres . Basically consolidation a lot of DB's into one db.

The problem i have is when no activity in a database for some time disk is filling up . I want to control how much storage can be used by WAL . I adjusted the wal_segments to keep. Still disk is filling up . 
Rather than doing some dummy update to a table , are there any parameters i can set to control the disk usage . 
Current parameters are

```
wal_keep_segments =4 
wal_max_size =128 
wal_min_size 16
```

Murali

Comment: How about `archive_mode`, and `archive_command` parameters?

Comment: @SahapAsci This is AWS RDS, they don't have access to that.

Comment: @Murali, can you please run `SHOW shared_preload_libraries` on an instance and paste the result here?

Comment: rdsutils that is only one shows up.

Comment: Does AWS RDS has [archive_timeout](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-ARCHIVE-TIMEOUT)?